# How to enable horizontal scroll bar in GNU Emacs for linux ubuntu?

Tags: emacs

How can u put a horizontal scroll bar with "don't wrap"?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can enable it through the customize interface.

1. Press `M-x customize-variable`
2. Enter `horizontal-scroll-bar-mode`
3. Click Value Menu, choose `t` to enable horizontal scroll bars.
4. Click Apply and Save.